# Lemme 2.4 in Morse theory by Milnor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, manifolds, morse-theory

This is lemma 2.4 from "Morse theory" by Milnor ,with the prove 
[image]
[image]

I have some questions about this prove :

1) why  $\displaystyle\frac{dc}{dt}(f)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{fc(t+h)-fc(t)}{h}$ and who is $f$ ?

2)Why the differential equation has locally one solution which depends on the initial conditions ?

3) what is the purpose of the last step "let $\varepsilon _0>0,\dots$"

Please help me

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Tangent vectors can be viewed as derivations on the space of smooth functions on a manifold.  The action of $\frac{dc}{dt}$ on a function is the direction derivative of the function in the direction $\frac{dc}{dt}$.  So $\frac{dc}{dt}(f) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(c(t+h)) - f(c(t))}{h}$ by definition.

2)  This is a standard result in ODEs.  You could check the reference Milnor provides.  You can also find a proof in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.  Here is a MathOverflow [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18976/smooth-dependence-of-odes-on-initial-conditions) with some more references.
3) I am not sure what you mean by "the last step."  Do you mean the last two paragraphs?  Milnor has shown that "for each point in $M$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ and a number $\varepsilon>0$ so that" the differential equation generates a unique smooth flow ($1$-parameter group of diffeomorphisms) on $U$ for $|t|<\varepsilon$.    We want to show that each of these flows can be pieced together into a global flow on $M$.

The support of the vector field is compact, so we can cover it with finitely many neighborhoods which admit flows.  As the flow at each point is unique, we definitely get a global flow as long as $|t|$ is less than $\varepsilon$ defined above.  As we only need finitely many neighborhoods, there is a smallest such $\varepsilon$ called $\varepsilon_0$.  Now I know that for $|t| < \varepsilon_0$, there is a global flow.

Comment: Thank you thank you for the answer , so if i understand for 2) , the D.E hase locally a unique solution because $X$ is $C^{\infty}$ right ?

Comment: Certainly $C^\infty$ is enough. I think that condition can be relaxed significantly.  For example, I think much of Morse's work was with $C^3$ functions.

Comment: i mean when we have a ed $y'(t)=f(t,y)$ ,with an initial condition ,we say that it has a localy solution because f is locally lipshitz for example or we use Peano , now in the theoren they say that X is smooth vector field on M SO IT IS $C^{\infty}$ ,  
Now what i must say ? ,the E.D has a locally solution because ... ? please ,thank you

Comment: you understand me please ?

Comment: Every continuously differentiable function is locally Lipschitz, right?

Comment: yes, every continuously differentiable function is locally Lipschitz ; so?

Comment: So Picard-Lindelof suffices to show that the differential equation has a solution, as you said before.  I don't think I understand what you are asking.

Comment: ok, but i want to know the E.D has a unique solution because X is $C^{\infty}$ or because $\varphi$ is $C^{\infty}$ please

Comment: Oh, I see -- $\phi$ exists and is smooth because $X$ is smooth.

Comment: so the ED has a unique locally solution because X is smooth right ?

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: you can help me please ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377207/an-other-question-about-theorem-3-1-from-morse-theory-by-milnor

Comment: please why we have that $\phi_{t+s}=\phi_t\circ \phi_s$

Comment: I also think it helps to say that if at a point the derivative is zero, the unique solution of the ODE is to have $\varphi_t(p) = p$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. I'm saying this because at the end of the proof he covers $K$ with finitely many open neighborhoods $U_i$ (which might contain some points not in $K$). Then he sets $\varphi_t(q) = q$ for $q\not\in K$, and we need to make sure it agrees with the $\varphi$ defined in the $U_i$'s. They agree because the only flow through the critical points is the constant flow.