# An other question about Theorem 3.1 from Morse theory by Milnor

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, manifolds, morse-theory

In the proof of theorem 3.1 they put : $\langle X,\nabla f \rangle =X(f)$ after that they say that:
for a curve $c$ on $M$ then $\left\langle\dfrac{\mathrm{d}c}{\mathrm{d}t},\nabla f\right\rangle=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}(f\circ c)}{\mathrm{d}t}$

[image]

[image]

I have three question please:

1) What is the purpose of seeing that $t\rightarrow f(\varphi_t(q))$ is linear with derivative +1 ?

2)How to see that $\varphi_{b−a}$ is a difeomorphisme and it's carrie $M^a$ homeomorphicly onto $M^b$

3)Why $r_1$ is a retraction from $M^a$ to $M^b$ ?

Please ,help me

Thank you

Comment: The purpose of (1) is to make (2) obvious and to make it easy to write down a formula for $r_t$. Can you construct a simple example (e.g. for domains in $\mathbb{R}^2$) and see what he is doing? Can you say more about where you are stuck?

Comment: Thank's for your answer , but i don't the relation between the fac that $f(\varphi_t(q))$ is linear with dervative=+1 and the fact that $\varphi_{b-a}$ is a diffeomorphisme ,...?

Comment: The fact that it is a diffeomorphism onto its image follows just from the existence/uniqueness of ODE, the long-time existence (essentially by construction) and smoothness with respect to initial condition. I.e. this is standard ODE theory.

Comment: The tricky part is that $\phi_{b-a}$ maps $M^a$ to $M^b$. To check this, calculate what $f( \phi_{b-a}(x))$ is, if $f(x) \le a$. This is where you use the fact that your new vector field flows downwards so that the time $t$ flow changes the value of $f$ by $t$.

Comment: @SamLisi , where is the D.E ? and why $\phi_{b-a}$ is a diffeomorphisme from M^a to M^b  please please, thank you

Comment: Do you understand what $\phi_t$ is?

Comment: yes yes it's ok $\phi_t$ is 1-parameter groupe of diffeomorphisme , because $\phi_t$ is a diffeomorphisme then $\phi_{b-a}$ is a diffeomorphisme ?

Comment: i don't understand this part of the answer given by @paul siegel :and repeating the argument but reversing the direction of the gradient flow for $f$ shows that $\phi_{b-a} \colon M^a \to M^b$ is onto.  This should answer (1) and (2) , can you help me please ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8567/discussion-between-sam-lisi-and-vrouvrou)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $t \mapsto f(\phi_t(q))$ is linear with derivative $1$ implies that $f(\phi_t(q)) = t + c$ for some constant $c$ (as long as $\phi_t(q) \in f^{-1}[a,b]$).  Take a point $q$ such that $f(q) = a$.  Since $\phi_0 = id$, we have $a = f(q) = f(\phi_0(q)) = c$; thus $f(\phi_t(q)) = t + a$.  In particular $f(\phi_{b-a}(q)) = b - a + a = b$, so $\phi_{b-a}(q)$ maps $M^a$ into $M^b$.  $\phi_t$ is automatically a diffeomorphism onto its image for every $t$, and repeating the argument but reversing the direction of the gradient flow for $f$ shows that $\phi_{b-a} \colon M^a \to M^b$ is onto.  This should answer (1) and (2).

As for (3), there is nothing to prove: just look up the definition of "retraction" and stare at the formula for $r_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , what you mean by $\phi_t$ is automatically a diffeomorphism onto it's image ? please

Comment: please what you mean by : repeating the argument but reversing the direction of the gradient flow for f shows that ϕb−a:Ma→Mb is onto

Comment: @Vrouvrou: the local flow of a vector field is always a diffeomorphism.  This is essentially by uniqueness of solutions to ODE's; see any basic textbook on smooth manifolds (which you should really read before Morse Theory).

Comment: @Vrouvrou: if you believe that the gradient flow of $f$ sends the set $f \leq a$ into $f \leq b$, then the same argument shows that the gradient flow of $-f$ sends $f \geq b$ to $f \geq a$.

Comment: hi nice to see you : that's ok i think that i understand the idea , i just have i question for 3 , why r_1 is a retraction and r_0 is the identity then r_t is a deformation retract, ? we must prove that r_t is contious and onto befor no ? thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou: A deformation retract is just a homotopy between the identity map and a retract.  If you believe that $r_0$ is the identity and $r_1$ is a retract, then you just need to convince yourself that $r_t(q)$ is continuous in $q$ and $t$.  I suppose there is something going on here: the flow map $\phi$ is defined by solving ordinary differential equations, so we are using the fact that the solutions to such equations depend smoothly on the initial condition.